# JS event once element is added to DOM?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firebug

This is for debugging purposes so to find which part of code creates/modifies the element.

Is there a way to set up a breakpoint ir callback event once specified ***ID/CLASS*** element has been added/modified?

Of course there may be another way so would like to hear that too.

Comment: a jquery plugin `livequery` is generally used for this.

Comment: The inspector can't be used to watch on DOM elements creation/removal.

Comment: I was going to suggest the new(ish) `MutationObserver` object ([DOM4](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_Mutation_Observers)) that some browsers support (Chrome 18+, Firefox 14+, and Safari 6+). But as Rob W pointed out on my now-deleted answer, the callback you get from the `MutationObserver` is asynchronous, so you can't break on it. :-(

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks anyway! It was something I have never heared of so your answer had value for me :).

Answer (score 1):

With the DevTools, it is impossible to get the exact solution, but you may try a variation of this:

1. Bring up the DevTools (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd>), switch to the Elements panel.
2. Right-click the desired context (parent) element.
3. In the context menu, select `Break on...` - `Subtree Modifications`.

As it says, the DevTools will break on the code that modifies successor nodes of the context element. You can also set the `Node Removal` breakpoint in a similar way, which will break on the context element removal.

Comment: Thanks, I was using this method, however it doesn't work for me and my  js/ajax heavy app :(